# Double.Parse fails in german locale

Tags: c#, mono

I have a raspberry pi with system language set to "de_DE.UTF-8" and mono version 3.28 installed. My programs need to convert `Strings` into `Doubles`, but I ran into a few problems:

```
Double.Parse("500", NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Works just fine.

```
Double.Parse("500.123", NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Throws `FormatException`, what is weird.

```
Double.Parse("500,123", NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"));
```

Throws `FormatException` too;

The funny thing is if I change my system language (sudo raspi-config) to "en-GB.UTF-8" all functions work as expected. Anyone knows how to solve this as a German user I would like to use German system settings.

Comment: You ought to file a bug with the Mono project.  Or fix it yourself, largely the point of Open Source.

Comment: Imo problem is not with culture/parsing itself but with Mono handling float/double on ARMHF(Raspberry PI). Can user confirm that he is using 3.2.8 with mono --version because versions before 3.2.7 had problems with floats on armhf.

Comment: My mono --version:
Mono JIT compiler version 3.2.8 (Debian 3.2.8+dfsg-4+rpi1)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
 TLS:           __thread
 SIGSEGV:       normal
 Notifications: epoll
 Architecture:  armel,vfp+hard
 Disabled:      none
 Misc:          softdebug 
 LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
 GC:            sgen

It seems mono 3.27 just brought initial armhf port.
@HansPassant I looked into source of Double.cs. I think /master/mcs/class/corlib/System/Double.cs at 533 following is doing this.
But i can´t find for code ParseImpl.

Comment: @HansPassant I filled a bug report. [Bug 18830](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=18830)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is fixed in mono 3.4 which is not yet uploaded in raspberry repo